# Write to a file on a server using python

Tags: python, file, server

I want to write some data, e.g. "hello" on a file that is located on a remote server, not a local server. This is the code that I used to read from server:

```
import urllib2

var = "hello"
url = "http://url:port/log/log.txt"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
txt = response.read();
print txt
```

As an output I was able to get the data from the log file.
Now I want to write some data, e.g. "hello" onto the same file. How to achieve that?

Comment: Well, you can't just write data to a server if the latter doesn't let you do this. So, you must set it up accordingly. While doing so, you should think how it should accept such data and write it. It's normally done with PUT and POST methods of HTTP.

Comment: Well server is configured to allow users to write into files, that is not the problem. I thought of HTTP but most of the posts included examples like these, urllib or something else. Never looked into HTTP methods. Can I directly write to the file without running any server side script on the server? I am not running any script on the server actually. Sorry if i didnt mention that.

Comment: No, you cannot, unless your server is running some kind of file transfer protocol. If it's not running _anything_, then if you could write to its files, that'd be considered a major vulnerability. So, you can set up some Python or PHP script to deal with file uploads, then connect to it using your local script.

Comment: My thoughts on HTTPs exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code is doing is actually not "reading a file" but sending an HTTP get request to a given url and print the HTTP response's body. What you get as content for this url is up to the HTTP server serving this url, and the fact it actually comes from a file stored on this server is totally irrelevant -  it might as well come from a database, from another web server, or be typed in real time by a monkey FWIW.

If you want to use the HTTP protocol to modify the content of a given file on this server, the server must provide this service (as a given url where you're supposed to send a POST or PUT http request with the new content).